# API Key Invalid when making GET request to Mailchimp API

Tags: java, android, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

For some reason, I am unable to access the API via my Android app. I have used the same credentials via Mac terminal, and have received a successful response.

This is the current code I am using:

```
String url = "https://" + dc + ".api.mailchimp.com/3.0/";
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "basic " + Base64.encode("saroy:myapikey".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
conn.connect();
```

I also tried an alternative method, but this returns an `API Key Missing` response:

```
Authenticator.setDefault (new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication ("saroy", "myapikey".toCharArray());
    }
});
```

Comment: Is your _userandpass_ variable in the format _username:password_? Also, try a capital "B" in "basic" - it shouldn't matter but I've come across some fussy APIs.

Comment: Yeah. I actually didn't pass it as a variable, but as a string. Changed "basic" to "Basic" but still no luck.

Comment: Using Fiddler (or something similar), what does the raw HTTP request look like? Can you check the raw HTTP request of the one that works against the one that doesn't?